# Problems running program using shared memory; seg fault sometimes; shmmax and shmall have something to do with it?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

HI,

I have a program in which a master processes spawns N workers who will invert, each one, each row of an image, giving me an inverted image at the end. The program uses shared memory and posix semaphores, unnamed sems, more spefically and I use shmctl with IPC_RMID and sem_close and sem_destroy in the terminate() function.
However, when I run the program several times, sometimes it gives me a segmentation fault and is in the first shmget. I've already modified my shmmax value in the kernel, but I can't do the same to the shmall value, I don't know why.

Can someone please help me? Why this happens and why isn't it all the time? The code seems fine, gives me what I want, efficient and so...but sometimes I have to reboot Ubuntu to be able to run it again, even thought I'me freeing the resources.

Please enlighten me!

EDIT:

Here are the 3 files needed to run the code + the makefile:
http://pastebin.com/JqTkEkPv
http://pastebin.com/v7fQXyjs
http://pastebin.com/NbYFAGYq

http://pastebin.com/mbPg1QJm

You have to run it like this ./invert someimage.ppm outimage.ppm
(test with a small one for now please)

Here are some values that may be important:

```
$ipcs -lm
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 262144
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608
min seg size (bytes) = 1

$ipcs -ls

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 128
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767
```

EDIT: the seg fault was solved! I was allocating an **array in shared memory and that was a little bit odd.So, I've allocated segment for an *array only and voilà. If you want, check the new code and comment.

Comment: That's gonna be difficult without access to the code.

Comment: If you are able to narrow down to the area of code causing the Segmentation Fault, paste those offending lines here.

Comment: I've edited the post in order for you to see the links with all the source code

Comment: If you run my code several times, perhaps after 5-6 times you get this error, that is what I'm getting now: shmget to allocate image struct failed. Errno returned:  No space left on device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you posted your code we can say a bit more.

Without having read all in detail, I think the cleanup phase of your `main` looks suspicious. In fact it seems to me that all your worker processes will perform that cleanup phase too.

After the fork you should more clearly distinguish what `main` does and what the workers do. Alternatives:

- Your main process could just
  `wait` on the `pid`s of the workers
  and only then do the rest of
  processing and cleanup.
- All the worker processes could
  return in `main` after the call to
  `worker`.
- Call `exit` at the end of the worker
  function.

---

**Edit after your code update:**

I think still a better solution would be to do a classical `wait` for all the processes.

Now let's look into your worker process. In fact these never terminate, there is no `break` statement in the `while (1)` loop. I think what is happening is that once there is no more work to be done

- the worker is stuck in
  `sem_wait(sem_remaining_lines)`
- your main process gets notified of
  the termination
- it destroys the `sem_remaining_lines`
- the worker returns from `sem_wait`
  and continues
- since `mutex3` is also already
  destroyed (or maybe even unmapped) the wait on it returns
  immediately
- now it tries to access the data, and
  depending on how far the `main`
  process got on destruction the data
  is mapped or not and the worker
  crashes (or not)

As you can see you have many problems in there. What I would do to clean up this mess is

- `waitpid` before destroy the shared
  data
- `sem_trywait` instead of the 1 in
  `while (1)`. But perhaps I didn't completely understand your control flow. In any case, give them a termination condition.
- capture all returns from system
  functions, in particular the `sem_t`
  family. These can be interrupted by
  IO, so you definitively **must**
  check for `EINTR` on these.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try and do those changes and then I'll post it.Thanks

Comment: You can see my first new link in my post, please? I've done more or less the changes I told me but without success...I still have problems with shmget after 5-6 runs ... :(

Comment: I changed a bit, instead of allocating sh_mm to an **array I did it a simple pointer, because shmat returns (void)*. So, the seg fault was solved. Now, I did some changes based on what you told me, could please check for some inconsistencies? I will re-edit the 1st link

Answer (score 3):

If all your `sem_t` POSIX semaphores are unnamed you should only use `sem_init` and `sem_destroy` on them and never `sem_close`.